# Question regarding infinite sets of a metric space.

Tags: analysis

Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ be subsets of a metric space $X$.

(a)If $B_n = \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$, prove that closure  $\overline {B_n} = \cup_{i=1}^n \overline {A_i}$.

(b)If $B = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$, prove that $\overline B \supset \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A_i}$

(c) Show and example so that (b) gives a proper subset.

---

I was trying to solve this problem and the following is my answer.
I have no idea how to solve (c). Can someone check my work ?

(a): Suppose $x\in \overline B_n $. Then by definition, $\exists A_i \subset B_n$ such that $x\in A_i$ where x is a point or $\exists \overline{A_i} \subset \overline{B_n}$ such that $x$ is a limit point that belongs to $\overline A_i$. In the latter case, taking the neighborhood of $x$, there exists a point other than $x$, say, $y$ that belongs to some $A_i$. Therefore, $\overline {B_n} = \cup_{i=1}^n \overline {A_i}$.

(b):Let $x\in\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline {A_i}$. Then $x$ must be a point that belongs to some $A_i$ or be a limit point that belongs to some $\overline{A_i}$.  Now in order to get a contradiction, assume that $x$ does not belong to the closure of $B$. Then $x$ neither belongs to $B$ nor $\overline{B}$. Therefore $x\in B^c$ and must be an interior point. Since $B^c = \cap_{i=1}^{\infty} {A_i}^c$, $x$ does not belong to any of the $A_i$, contrary to our initial assumption. Thus all points in $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline {A_i}$ belongs to $\overline B$.

(c) I actually have no clue :(

---

I'm just trying to learn something step by step here.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused on your reasoning for $(a)$. If I was your grader I dont know I would like that answer to be honest. Where do you get the "or there exists $\bar{A}_i\subset B_n$"?

Perhaps try something along the lines: Let $x\in \bar{B}_n$. Then $x$ is a limit point of $B_n$ or $x\in B_n$ (but this is case is easy since if $x\in B_n$, then $x\in A_i$ for some $i$, so $x\in \bar{A}_i$, and the result follows). Thus, for all $\epsilon>0$ the ball of radius $\epsilon$ center at $x$ ($B(r,x)$) will contain points of $B$ other than $x$. Then, consider the sequence of balls: $B(1,x),B(1/2,x),B(1/3,x),...,B(1/n,x),...$Note that it must be the case that there is some $A_i$ such that $B(1/n,x)\cap A_i$ is not empty for all $i$ (otherwise there are $N_i$ such that when the radius drops below $1/N_i$ then $A_i$ does not touch your ball. Let $N$ be the max of the $N_i$ and then consider $B(1/N,x)$, this would not touch any of the $A_i$ so it would not touch $B$, a contradiction with the fact that $x$ is a limit point). Then, we can now claim that $x\in \bar{A}_i$ for such an $i$, and hence $x\in \cup \bar{A}_i$.

Here note what could possible go wrong in the infinite case. Try to think of an example so that whenever the radius goes smaller you have to use a new $A_i$.

For the other inclusion, if $x\in \cup \bar{A}_i$, and so $x\in \bar{A}_i$ for some $i$.So $x\in A_i$ or $x$ is a limit point of $A_i$. For the first case note that then $x\in B\subset \bar{B}$. For the second case then there is an $i$ so that $x\in \bar{A}_i$. Let $B(r,x)$ be arbitrary. Then by definition we have that the ball contains other points in $A_i$, but $A_i\subset B$, so it contains points in $B$, so $x\in \bar{B}$. Note that this also works for the infinite case so part $(b)$ follows.

Again, try to come up with an example so that there is an $x$ in the closure of $B$, so that for each index $i$, you can come up with a radius small enough so that $A_i$ does not touch $B(r,x)$.

Comment: Knowing that $x\in\overline{B_n}$ is not sufficient to conclude that $x$ is a limit point of $B_n$.

Comment: @CameronBuie oops sorry. I edited accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For c) take a converging sequence $x_i$ with limit point $x$ such that $x\not= x_i$ for all $i$. Then define $A_i=\{x_i\}$. Obviously $\bar A_i=A_i$ and therefore $x\in \bar B$ but $x\not\in \bigcup_i \bar A_i$.